# Find out the centos version update command will update it to

Tags: centos7

I have an old server with centos 7.5 running.
Now I wish to upgrade it. However before running the update command, I want to check the version it will be upgraded it to so as to check the software compatibility. However when I run the check-update command I get a full list of packages without mentioning the centos version it will be updated to. How can we find the version.
Please note I do not want upgrade to centos 8 as this server will be running another 6 months , till the new software and server will updated and running again.
Kindly see the command and output.
Command Used

```
sudo yum check-update
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of the `centos-release` package that will be installed.

That is what determines the "release".

Be aware  that CenOS 7.5 [was released](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#CentOS_version_7) in 2018 and the final "release" from CentOS 7 is `7.9` from 2020.

**Note** A normal `yum update` will upgrade your system with ***all bug fixes and security updates*** that have been released since you last upgraded and won't stop at a specific release point. In other words, *your system will be made current* and won't limit the upgrades to those that were released between 2018 when you installed CentOS 7.5 and what was included in the 7.9 release from 2020. You should much get more than that.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS (and RHEL-based distros in general) does not support staying on old point releases, or cherry-picking updates. You will be exposed to security vulnerabilities, and the first advice you will get from people is to  `yum update`  everything.

First take a backup of the OS, as you seem to want to be cautious. Then `yum update`  ideally on a test system first.

Applications should be supporting the latest major version, so "EL 7". Anything "certifying" or otherwise requiring you to stay on an old version like "7.5" is bad practice, and a bug.